# entering regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add this regular expression ^[a-zA-Z0-9,.&#-]{1-45}@[a-zA-Z]{1-45}.[a-z]{3}$  to validate email addresses to this javascript code.

```
if(email=="" || email==null) 
    {               
        document.getElementById("em_error").innerHTML="*You must enter your Email Address";
        error=true;
        return false;
    }
else
    document.getElementById("em_error").innerHTML="";
```

Comment: You can add your regular expression to your input field directly. Here is the example link..  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match` function.

```
if(email=="" || email==null || !email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9,.&#-]{1-45}@[a-zA-Z]{1-45}.[a-z]{3}$/,i))
```

**NOTE**

Please review your pattern, because there should be longer and shorter TLD then 3 characters, like `.museum`, `.eu`, `.nowanytldcantakenformoney`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as shown below (using `RegExp.test` function):

```
...
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9,.&#-]{1-45}@[a-zA-Z]{1-45}.[a-z]{3}$/;
if (!email || !re.test(email)) {  // if the input value is empty or doesn't match the needed pattern
    document.getElementById("em_error").innerHTML="*You must enter your Email Address";
    error = true;
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("em_error").innerHTML="";
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test